# Can't update via Gridview anymore

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

For some reason, whenever I try to use the update feature, it gives me the "No value given for one or more parameters" error. Here's my queries.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2]" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE [ID] = ?"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Table2 SET [BlogTitle] = ?, [Image] = ?, [PicText] = ?, [TravelDate] = ?, [BeginText] = ?, [Caption] = ?, [City] = ?, [Country] = ?, [EndText] = ? WHERE [ID] = ? " >

    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

It was working a couple days ago, don't know what changed. I also tried using "@BlogTitle" instead of ? in the update command. Nothing giving.

Comment: Also, another query on another page I have gives me the same error...

Comment: u take all the columns of table 2 in your updatecommand???

Comment: Well, I might update them all, I might not. It's using a gridview and using the Edit command. @amitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about this, try to insert

```
<UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>    or </SelectParameters>
```

Good luck.

Comment: No luck... It was working before without that, that's what is crazy.

Comment: This actually did work... Maybe it didn't work before because I didn't do it in the correct order...